# Swf loses keyboard focus in flash cs3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard, focus

I am using Adobe Flash CS3 to create a project. I need to utilize the keyboard. When I publish the swf file for testing, it registers only a select number of keys on the keyboard. I have noticed, in the background, that the flash window is responding to key commands, and any keys pressed that are not key commands register in the swf.

For instance, when the swf is running, and I press "D", there is no issue, the swf picks it up and tells me that I pressed that key. When I press "T", the swf does not pick it up, and the "text window" pops up in flash.

Is there a preference that will fix this?

And yes, I have tried clicking on the swf window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much blood, sweat, and tears, I found the answer to my own question. If you have the same problem that I do, in the swf window, click the dropdown menu "control", and click "disable keyboard shortcuts". Now, flash will no longer try to steal your precious keyboard entries.